# Coherence Asynchronous Get/Put .Net

Tags: .net, oracle-coherence

I want to use the coherence client library to asynchronously put items into a named cache. Unfortunately it appears to me that Oracle's client libraries for .Net doesn't have async operations at all.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How about creating your own async methods using that library?

Comment: yeah well this is what I wanted to avoid. Additionally the IO operation it would boil down to would be blocking anyways...

Answer (score 0):

I also have a need to use an async version of this. I will probably add a Coherence implementation to the [CacheSharp library](https://github.com/paulfryer/CacheSharp), but it will have to be a wrapper around the sync API until Oracle provides a real async API. However by using the CacheSharp IAsynCache interface you are decoupled from the underlying implementation so a change in the future to a better performing Confluence implementation will be transparent.